# Why aren't discord.py bots playing audio through voice chat?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am writing a discord bot using the discord.py rewrite and it is not playing audio through the voice chat. I have also tested bots written by others, and those bots are not playing audio either. Why isn't my bot working?

Here is my code:

```py
import os
import io
import aiohttp

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio

token = "" #add token here

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot("$")



@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord')
    
@bot.command(name="testsound")
async def testsound(ctx):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
        
        vc = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('file source') #path to file
        
        vc.play(audio_source)
        vc.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(audio_source, volume=1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the code and it works fine, it does play audio (.mp3).
So I supposed you did not install FFmpeg.

Additionally, you have to install [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) as this is the audio player discord.py supports. Make sure to add the /bin folder of FFmpeg to your `PATH` on Windows.

Comment: I installed FFmpeg on both WSL Ubuntu and Windows to test my code. The bot is still not working on either platform.